# Can I visit the USA as a VWP tourist immediately prior to entry on non-tourist visa?

Tags: visas, usa, us-visa-waiver-program, h1b-visas

Here's my situation: I'm a UK citizen. I have an H-1B visa to work in the US as of 1 August. I also have a valid ESTA.

I would like to go to the US in July for a holiday, immediately prior to beginning my work. The holiday would be at the other end of the country from my work.

I can't enter with the H-1B as I can only enter the US on that visa 10 days prior to starting work.

**Specific question:** Would it be possible to visit the US in early July on the VWP, visit Canada/Mexico for a few days in late July, and re-enter the US with my H-1B visa?

**General question:** Is it possible to visit the US on the VWP, leave briefly, and re-enter on a different status (e.g. H, F, J, K, etc), without ever returning to one's home country?

I have posted this in Travel rather than Expatriates because, although in my specific case I have an H-1B visa, my question is more generally about VWP and travel, and I believe that it is applicable to travellers with non-immigrant visas.

There's a similar question [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10543/can-i-enter-the-usa-as-a-visitor-while-i-wait-for-an-h1-b-visa), although that's about going to the US and before having the H-1B visa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The possible snag with that plan is that in order to enter as a VWP traveler by air, you're supposed to **have a round-trip ticket** whereby you will end up somewhere that *is not* Canada or Mexico.

Based on the anecdotal evidence available to us, this rule is not really enforced consistently. However, it does provide an impeccable ground for the border officer to deny you entry if he doesn't like the color of your shoes. And it is possible that the airline will refuse boarding you if you have neither a valid visa nor a round-trip ticket.

If you do attempt this plan, you should expect that the border officer will notice the future visa in your passport, and be prepared to convince him that (a) you're not going to start work before you're allowed to, and (b) you *will* actually make the visa run later, because the rules do not allow you to change from VWP to H-1B status while in the US. At the least, bring documentation of your job offer with its start date, and preferably also tickets for the short trip to Canada or Mexico.

Comment: Would it make sense to carry a detailed itinerary? Including any hotel or car reservation receipts?

Comment: @mkennedy Yes it would

Comment: Thanks for this reply. In lieu of a return ticket, do you think that being able to demonstrate sufficient funds to get a return ticket if needed would suffice? I imagine that kind of thing is again subject to the whims of the border office.

Comment: @rturnbull: For the US, the actual legal rules require _specifically_ a "round-trip ticket". (This is in contrast to, for example, the Schengen rules that just ask for having the "means" to leave the area afterwards). So if the US border guards let you through despite knowing you _don't_ have an actual round-trip tickets, they would directly be breaking the rules. If you look sufficiently white, it is quite possible that you won't get _asked_ for your return arrangements -- but once they do ask, they will not have any legal way to be lenient.

Comment: @HenningMakholm the regulations define "round-trip ticket" to include tickets for onward travel, and the departure can be, oddly enough, as much as one year in the future.

Comment: I've entered the US three times on VWP with onward tickets rather than round-trip tickets. There wasn't any issue. Each time, the CBP officer asked me a couple of questions about my intended stay, had a look at my onward reservation and sent me on my way.

Comment: @phoog: My source is [8 CFR 217(2)(c)(1)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/217.2), which allows tickets for onward travel only "as long as the trip does not terminate in contiguous territory or an adjacent island". So Canada or Mexico is not enough, at least by the rules-as-written.

Comment: @HenningMakholm that is correct.  My point is that this plan would comply with the statutory requirement if the traveler arrived with a ticket to any destination outside of North America, for example a holiday trip to the UK or elsewhere, whether for December or any other time before the following July.

Comment: @phoog: Right. In any case, my point in the comment you were (I think) replying to was mainly that the OPs suggestion of having "sufficient funds to get a return ticket if needed" rather than the ticket itself will not suffice under the rules.