# Can I enter on an ESTA while I have an F1 visa?

Tags: visas, esta, study, f1-visas

I’m going to the US for a vacation in July - August 10th. I also am starting a course on September 10 and I will have an F1 visa. Can I enter the USA in July on a ESTA if I have the F1 visa already in my passport and then leave the states 30 days before the programme starts and enter back in on the F1 Visa? Or would it be best to come back to my country and apply for the visa after my vacation?

Comment: Yes you can do that. [One is actually allowed to have two different US visas at the same time](https://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/holding-two-us-visas-at-the-same-time--565856.html) and by extension you can have an ESTA and an F1 simultaneously.

Comment: Do you know if I would have to apply for a change of status?

Comment: Similar: [Can I visit the USA as (ESTA) tourist immediately prior to entry on non-tourist visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90068/can-i-visit-the-usa-as-esta-tourist-immediately-prior-to-entry-on-non-tourist)

Comment: Change of status for what? You are entering with ESTA, exiting back home, and coming back with F1. There is no status to be changed.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments/questions.  Putting on hold for now.